# Magento 2.2 integration callback URL is not receiving OAuth data

Tags: integration, oauth, magento2.2.0, callback

I'm trying to implement OAuth 1.0a in Magento 2.2. As per Magento docs, I created an integration, providing a Ngrok URL that points to localhost:8080 of my computer as the callback URL. However, when I'm activating the integration, my callback URL endpoint receives no data, but I'm also not getting any errors when activating the integration.

I want to get the OAuth data that Magento claims to send to the callback URL to continue OAuth authentication, but I'm now stuck at this point as Magento doesn't send it.

How can I overcome this issue? Any helpful suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This had happened because I had not provided a URL to the *Identity Link* field. Not providing that had caused Magento to generate both consumer keys and access keys at the moment of activating the integration and not send the OAuth callback data to the callback URL. Providing a valid URL for the *Identity Link* field solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** I am also facing a similar issue, even though I have supplied both the callback and the identity link urls.

Anyone with an answer as to why this is happening. I'm fairly new to Magento

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/194693)